# How would I write an if/else statement for something that is undefined with a twig var?

Tags: javascript, json, twig

I'm using twig to declare a var user:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   {% if user is defined %}
   var user = {
    example: {{ userjson | raw }}
   };
   {% endif %}
 </script>
```

This checks to see if a user is logged in, if not my console returns this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

I want to be able to display a message if the user is not defined but I can't think of a way to do that. Right now I have this:

```
if(user){
    console.log('hello');
} else {
    console.log('undefined');
}



// This checks is the user information
var userId = user.example.id;


console.log(user.example.money);
```

Comment: Keep in mind the test `is defined` will also return `true` for `null`-values

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured this out:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   {% if user is defined %}
   var user = {
    example: {{ userjson | raw }}
   };
   {% else %}
   var user = false;
   {% endif %}
 </script>
```

Then I just check to see if the var user is false, and if it's not then I do something else.